# How to use docker container as github action step from private repository

Tags: docker, image, github, containers, action

Say I have a workflow:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: login to registries
        uses: actions/login@master
      - name: step with container
        uses: docker://private.repo.io/my-image:1
```

But the github action tries to pull `my-image:1` immediately, before the job is even run, instead of following the steps order and pulling it when it's needed. How do I approach that?

I've seen that there is `credentials` map, when using `container` to run whole job in the container, but I didn't find such solution for containers run as step. Is there a solution to it?